# Not automatically built by drone.io

Tags: go, drone.io

Set trigger/ref in drone.yaml.
This is the expected behavior of the build at develop/master push and when creating merge requests, but it is not happening!

```
--drone.yaml--
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

trigger:
  ref:
  - refs/heads/master
  - refs/heads/**
  - refs/pull/*/head

steps:
- name: test
  image: golang
  commands:
  - cd src/chat
  - go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth
  - go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/providers/facebook
  - go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/providers/github
  - go get github.com/stretchr/gomniauth/providers/google
  - go test
  - go build main.go auth.go client.go room.go
```

[Manual Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFiN0.png)
[github webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6oVz.png)

How can I build automatically in response to push and pull requests?

Answer (score 0):

All the details can be found in this documentation https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/triggers/

You can use something like this to achieve your requirement

```
trigger:
  branch:
    include:
    - develop
    - master
  event:
    include:
    - push
    - pull_request
```